# L^p convergence and a.s. convergence

Tags: probability-theory

I got a question regarding both the above mentioned convergence types.

Consider a sequence $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of random variables on a certain probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$. Let $p \geq 1$ and assume that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \Vert X_n \Vert_p^p = x < \infty$. Then we can not conclude wether or not $X_n$ converges almost surely.

But could we conclude, that

$\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n < \infty$ almost surely?

My idea was that if we would assume that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n = \infty$, then we find a subsequence $X_{n_k}$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty} X_{n_k} = \infty$ a.s. and hence

$\lim_{k\to\infty} \Vert X_{n_k} \Vert_p^p = \infty$ and hence $\lim_{n\to\infty} \Vert X_n \Vert_p^p = \infty$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, consider the case where $X_n$ are iid standard normal. Then $\limsup X_n = \infty$ a.s., but the $L^p$ norm is constant and hence convergent.

In particular, $\limsup X_n=\infty$ a.s. does not imply $||X_n||_p\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm deadlost with the $L^p$ and a.s. convergence stuff.